# How to explain conditional independence between two nodes in a Bayesian network for some values of another node but not all?

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, bayesian-network, networks

Imagine three back to back directed nodes.

A -> B -> C

Knowing B, A and C are ought to become independant. Imagine B to be binary 
A & C have positive correlation.

After I correct for B, for B=0, A & C become independent while for B=1 they become negatively correlated.

The network is learned by bnlearn in R, I;m showing a branch which is Markov Blanketed from the rest

I'm confused about the remaining correlation. Is it a sign that the network is not trained well or what?

Best

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, the contradiction. I'm describing an observation. the network is trained. adjusted for B= 0 A and C are independent. For B=1, they are not. That's an observation. I'm interested in knowing why. :)